# How to start a local server and open it in a browser from a shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, process

I have a test suite which runs in a browser (using QUnit, though that's unimportant). The test suite requires a local server running on a particular port. Running the tests currently involves a few steps:

1. `node test/server`
2. switch to browser of choice
3. open localhost:3000

I'd like to have a single command which starts the server then runs `open localhost:3000`. Ideally, the node process would remain in the foreground so it could be killed with ^C. I don't have a good understanding of subshells, so I'm not sure whether this is possible.

Comment: what OS? I think the answer may vary based on it

Comment: I'd like to support multiple platforms. I've already written a tiny program which forwards arguments to whichever "open" command is available: http://bit.ly/QB0Rof (commands beyond `open` and `xdg-open` could easily be added). The part I'm stuck on is doing something like `node test/server && open localhost:3000` (but which actually works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

- start a node.js service
- start a browser
- visit the service in the browser

First start the browser after a given delay. Next, start the service and let it run in the foreground. The double ampersand operator forces the "next" command to wait for the "first" command to exit with a code of 0, while the single ampersand means "start in background". We can use this to buy the service some time to warm up before the browser tries to access it.

```
#!/bin/sh
awhile=3
sleep $awhile && firefox http://localhost:3000/ & 
node netservice.js
```

If it helps, you can think of the `foo && bar &` as an async call that guarantees foo will finish before bar is called.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: This worked beautifully, and a 0.1 second sleep proved sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions say to open your browser of choice, as in Web browser, namely Firefox, Chrome, ahem... Internet Explorer.

Steps 2 and 3 are not command line at all. Step 3 is paste 'localhost:3000' into the browser's address bar. You can leave node running in the shell, or appen '&' which would start the process and return you to the prompt.

Comment: Right. I'm trying to automate the manual steps. OS X provides `open`, and other platforms provide similar commands for opening a resource in the appropriate application. The part I'm stuck on is making something like `node test/server && open localhost:3000` work.

Comment: Ah, I see. I knew I was misunderstanding something. Um, good luck.